# HDMI splitter with audio out

Tags: hdmi, splitters

I got a 22" monitor in my bed (it is hanged on the wall), it is connected to the computer using a HDMI cable, which can carry sound signal too. My problem is that my monitor doesn't have an audio out connector, so I can't plug my headphones in it.

And then, I need a device that can take the HDMI signal and split it in two:
- send the HDMI signal to the monitor
- provide an audio out 3.5 mm socket so I can connect my headphones in it

and then, the device should contain the following connectors:
- HDMI in, to recieve the signal from the computer
- HDMI out to connect to the monitor - or simply a short HDMI plug
- stereo 3.5 mm audio socket so I can connect my headphones in it

The device should be small enough so I can stick it to the back of the monitor.

Is there any device like this?

If not, then I probably need a computer monitor with audio out - this should be a common feature already, since the monitors with HDMI can already receive audio signals, so they should also offer that signal using an audio out connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably need a

- *HDMI to HDMI + Audio* like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KBHX072).
- This one should be coupled with a *RCA Male to 3.5mm* adapter [example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015J4OKZW).

with this setup you also need **two** HDMI cables.

Comment: So it's called *HDMI Audio Extractor*, that's what I needed to know. I prefer one that uses a single cable. To connect to the monitor, it should feature a HDMI plug, just like any HDMI cable  -  and then I can simply hang it by plugging it in to the monitor. I notice that such devices exist - for example [this one](http://ukhdmi.com/luxi-hdmi-audio-extractor-ahd-110_QQ103292)   -   thanx a lot!